# How does Salt handle different timezones?

Tags: timezone, zeromq, salt-stack

If the Salt-Master is in a different timezone* than a Minion, will that be a problem? How is it handled by Salt?

Or is it simply handled by 0mq?

*) or if the clock is off by some amount of time

Answer (score 0):

### The ZeroMQ part :

ZeroMQ, as has been setup since v2.x, does not interprete any content of any messages being sent/delivered beyond the transport per-se ( w.r.t. the documented transparent, broker-less message-passing behaviour and/or configuration settings ).

Expecting the ZeroMQ Framework to introduce any time-zone(s) / time-source(s) coordination side-effects is not fair.

ZeroMQ Framework may provide a trick to "centralise" a referential source of universal time, via a transparent port-forwarding to one, central, of the all locations connected with the use of the ZeroMQ tools. That singularity will permit to principally avoid any skewed TZ/time issues, yet such service meta-layer has to be designed and implemented by users' explicit code, which may use the ZeroMQ Framework tools for its well-known smart transparent message-passing services for doing it.